# Comparing chrono::duration with an integer

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am trying to compare the time elapsed to execute a piece of code with a fixed integer.

For example:

```
auto startProcessingTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
chrono::duration<int> timeDiff = (chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startProcessingTime));

    if (timeDiff > 12) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        continue;
    }
```

However on running this I get the following error:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('chrono::duration' and 'int')

How can I convert `timeDiff` to an integer?

I have also tried:

```
chrono::seconds s = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(timeDiff);
```

However,

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('chrono::seconds' (aka
>   'duration') and 'int')

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommended video tutorial on chrono which covers things like this, and why they are the way they are: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to tell it what `12` means. Is it seconds? Milliseconds? So either cast it:

```
chrono::seconds(12)
```

Or (my favorite) make it a chrono literal. If you mean 12 seconds, then:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
// ...

if (timeDiff > 12s) {
```

If it's milliseconds:

```
if (timeDiff > 12ms) {
```

Comment: Ah okay! Simple solution but somehow didn't find this when searching for the solution in the relevant docs! Thanks